# SSE implementation in Pedestal using individual channel per user

Tags: clojure, channel, server-sent-events, pedestal

I am working on an application that used to use websockets but due to scaling issues with them, we decided to replace them with server-sent events (SSE).

Our goal is to make it possible to create an SSE channel for every successfully logged user in order to be able to close this channel after user logout or session timeout in order not to consume unnecessary resources by unused channels remaining opened after the given user is logged out. These user channels we store in an atomic map registry and want to access the channel of the specific logged user (recognized by its session token used as a key in the registry) to send the messages to the frontend.

We used initally the **io.pedestal.http.sse** namespace but the problem with it is that it expects the handler to accept a "default" channel as route handler input argument and  if I try to use the separate user channel the messages are not received, for example in Postman I get empty response, the response contains the expected messages only if you rely on the "default" channel that the handler gets as input aregument:

(defn sse-handler [**channel** ctx]
...)

This the route using start-event-stream which returns an interceptor that uses the handler whenever a message has to be sent:

```
(def sse-route ["/rest/sse" :get (sse/start-event-stream sse-handler)
    :route-name :sse])
```

This is the handler:

```
(defn sse-handler [channel ctx]
  (doseq [[id {:keys [name data] :as payload}] @LIVE-NOTIFICATIONS]
    (when-not (chan/closed? channel)
      (async/>!! channel payload)
      (swap! LIVE-NOTIFICATIONS dissoc id)
      (Thread/sleep 1000)))
  (async/close! channel))
```

My question is: Is it possible to implement such a scenario using the individual user channel not the input one bolded above and how? Do I have to implement my own custom interceptor instead of using **start-event-stream** or I still can use the   **io.pedestal.http.sse** ns somehow? Or if I have to use the input argument channel is it possible for example to access it somehow to close it when the user is logged out?

Answer (score 0):

How about you try to handle SSE channel differently considering channels are handled by the server itself; not you.

Create a map of channels then use the channel from this map in your SSE handler

```
(defn channel-map [] (atom {}))
(defn get-user-channel [user-id channel-map](get @channel-map user-id))
```

```
(defn sse-handler [channel ctx]
(let [user-id (:user-id ctx)
     user-channel (get-user-channel user-id (channel-map))]
 (doseq [[id {:keys [name data] :as payload}] @LIVE-NOTIFICATIONS]
   (when-not (chan/closed? user-channel)
     (async/>!! user-channel payload)
     (swap! LIVE-NOTIFICATIONS dissoc id)
     (Thread/sleep 1000)))))
```

When you want to send a message to a user, you can use `async/>!!` to enqueue the message into the user's channel. For closing the user's channel, you can simply `dissoc` the user id from the channel map when the user logs out or the session timeout occurs.

Comment: This was the first thing I tried but the problem is that if the handler does not user the channel which it accepts as input argument, the messages are not sent successfully. 

I solved the problem, implemented my own SSE namespace analogically to the one implemented in Pedestal but adapted it to use the user channels that I create after user login and store in the atomic map. I will publish the solution later when I have more time.

Comment: A custom namespace that handles the individual user channels can certainly give you the flexibility and control you require for your application.